# Implementing functions like @LocalPort in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am contributing some framework and I am integrating it with Spring Boot. I want to create an annotation like `@LocalPort` that I made to use in testing.

I found `@LocalPort` to be `@Value` in the end, but I don't think I can't use it because the annotation I'm making needs to be passed another value. In the end I think I should inherit `ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` and either reimplement the `getSuggestedValue(...)` method or find another way. But I don't think this is the right way.

Is there another way to implement this?

For example,

```
@LocalSomePort(Protocol.HTTP) // Protocol.HTTPS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was late, but I solved it by adding a custom `BeanPostProcessor`.